# Protecting key in a file

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, password-protection

I generated private key from the following code:

```
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA","BC");
    kpg.initialize(512);
    KeyPair          pair = kpg.genKeyPair();
```

I want to store private key in file and i want to put password for the file to protect it.Is it possible programatically in JAVA??

I have seen openssl commands where it generates key and encrypts it,puts in a file and keeps password for that file.But i have no idea where the file is storing??
Anyway i want to put password by a javaprogram...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is to store your key within a **keystore**. There are a number of different formats of keystores, and Java tends to default to JKS (Java Key Store). These files can hold certificates and private keys, and are typically protected with a password, used to derive a key to encrypt the contents.

How to do this programmaticlly is documetned well in the javadoc for the `Keystore` class, where you can also find links to related classes you may need to use. Here is the link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of potential solutions. However you'll best served by re-using an existing standard.

E.g. you should be able to save your key-pair inside a password-protected PKCS#12 file - even if if does not include X.509 certificate(s). That will protect your key-pair and will be more future-proof if you ever need to reuse it on another system or from another language.